# Cold Plate Thermal Resistance

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction, fluent

I am designing a cold plate that will have 4 Power Modules Mounted on it. The total power loss from the modules is 5000W(1250W per Power Module). I have simulated the results on ANSYS Fluent and obtained the surface temperatures.

Now I am trying to calculate (by hand) the junction temperature of the each device.
[Each power module has 2 Junctions / 2 Devices]

The way I calculated the thermal resistance of the cold plate is:
(Max Surface temperature - Ambient Temperature)/Total Heat Loss(5000W)

Can I use this Cold Plate thermal resistance value to calculate each junction temperature for one module? Since the heat per module is not 5000w but 1250W, I am slightly unsure of the calculation method.

Thanks for your help!

**Boundary Conditions**:

Coolant inlet Temp: 65 Degrees Celsius

Rj = 0.04 c/w

Rc = 0.002 c/w

RS = 0.009 c/w

Comment: Not too many answers to choose from.  Maybe you should reveal some of the actual geometry, materials and how those values below subtitle Boundary Conditions are bound to the hopefully soon to be shown geometry.